# Правильный вызов данных из коллекции

Tags: c#, unity3d

Объясните мне, а то не врублюсь, как будет быстрее и лучше, и почему:

Так:

```
A = C.B["A"].GetComponent<Button>();
F = C.B["F"].GetComponent<Button>();
B = C.B["B"].GetComponent<Button>();
H = C.B["H"].GetComponent<Button>();
```

Или так:

```
C = C.B;
A = C["A"].GetComponent<Button>();
F = C["F"].GetComponent<Button>();
B = C["B"].GetComponent<Button>();
H = C["H"].GetComponent<Button>();
```

Или оба варианты равны?

`C.B` - это коллекция `new Dictionary<string, GameObject>()`;

Comment: Экономия на спичках.

Comment: Суровый BigO анализ )

Comment: Возможно целесообразнее хранить в словаре с сигнатурой **<string, Button>**, что бы не искать компонент "Кнопка"?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, вопрос не об этом.  Ко всему, с чего вы решили, что там только `Button`? Я же не просто так написал `GameObject`, то, что на примере, не значит, что там только `Button`.

Comment: Если это пример ради примера, то ответить невозможно и этот вопрос следует закрыть. Если вы в реальном проекте так храните какие-то важные сущности, то у вас, скорее всего, проблемы с архитектурой и эта экономия вряд ли хоть что-то ускорит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вообщем понял, бессмысленно использовать для этого `Dictionary` и `GetComponent`.
Так как есть`Transform`, мы можем в скрипте вызвать индекс `transform.GetChild(index)`.

```
public static Transform Transform(string Name) {
    Transform tm = c.transform;
    for (int i = 0; i < tm.childCount; ++i) {
        Transform child = tm.GetChild(i);
        if (child.name.Equals(Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static Transform Transform(GameObject Object, string Name) {
    Transform tm = Object.transform;
    for (int i = 0; i < tm.childCount; ++i) {
        Transform child = tm.GetChild(i);
        if (child.name.Equals(Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

По этому создавать еще одну промежность в виде `Dictionary<string,GameObject>`, а после еще и `GetComponent`, никакого смысла нет.

Другое дело, на сколько быстро будет работать `Equals` и есть ли решения лучше, для сравнения строк, не вариант: `child.name == Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Самое дорого здесь это GetComponent. Лучше ваши кнопки закешировать в словаре, если так надо. Dictionary. То, о чем, вы думаете - по времени выполнения даст разницу, несоизмеримо маленькую, по сравнению с вызовом GetComponent.

А вообще, что мешает самому проверить, что здесь будет быстрее?